# EFCore adding an Index could result in data loss?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add an Index to an existing EF Core Code First database, however I am getting a message saying that the scaffold may result in data loss - I have had a look through the migration and the SQL but it is not clear if it will - any ideas?

I have the following Model:

```
public class Likes
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Person { get; set; }

    public string JudgedPerson { get; set; }

    public int IsLike { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Person and JudgedPerson are GUIDs and I want to add an Index to these columns to speed up data access.

I have added the following in my AppDbContext OnModelCreating method to specify the index:

```
        builder.Entity<Likes>()
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.Person, p.JudgedPerson });
```

I have then run **dotnet ef migrations add**  --> This then gives the following message:

> An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy.

The resulting Migration code is showing:

```
public partial class AddIndexToLikesPersonJudgedPerson : Migration
{
   protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
   {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Person",
            table: "Likes",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "JudgedPerson",
            table: "Likes",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldType: "nvarchar(max)",
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Likes_Person_JudgedPerson",
            table: "Likes",
            columns: new[] { "Person", "JudgedPerson" });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Likes_Person_JudgedPerson",
            table: "Likes");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "Person",
            table: "Likes",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldNullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "JudgedPerson",
            table: "Likes",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldNullable: true);
    }
}
```

When I script this out, I get the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Likes]') AND [c].[name] = N'Person');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Likes] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [Likes] ALTER COLUMN [Person] nvarchar(450) NULL;

GO

DECLARE @var1 sysname;
SELECT @var1 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Likes]') AND [c].[name] = N'JudgedPerson');
IF @var1 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Likes] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var1 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [Likes] ALTER COLUMN [JudgedPerson] nvarchar(450) NULL;

GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Likes_Person_JudgedPerson] ON [Likes] ([Person], [JudgedPerson]);

GO

INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20211220123038_AddIndexToLikesPersonJudgedPerson', N'3.1.10');

GO
```

Comment: You are getting this message as it appears that column data type is being changed from `NVARCHAR( MAX )` to `NVARCHAR( 450 )`

Comment: Ok thanks - have run it through and no data appears to have been lost

Comment: I understood max is replaced by 450 when an index exists on this column. So I guess it is not possible to create an index on nvarchar max which is understandable. 
Now, I believe as well that this change was introduce at a certain EF core level (2.0.2?). So installing a newer EF core may lead to this change.